# BASH - Sed is failing to remove attribute lines filled with metacharacters

Tags: linux, perl, bash, scripting, sed

Im trying to correctly pass arguments to sed from a file named changesfile but I have been unsuccessful. It may be the contents of the file changesfile or the way im using the for loop. Im not sure.

The commands Im using:

```
cat changesfile | while read i ; do sed -e "s/$i//g" "filename" ; done
cat changesfile | while read i ; do sed -i "s/$i//g" "filename" ; done
cat changesfile | while read i ; do sed -e '/$i/d' filename ; done
cat changesfile | while read i ; do sed -e '/"$i"/d' filename ; done
```

I need to match certain lines in a file with tons of meta characters. The stuff im trying to match and remove is below:

```
fileattribute[hostname.stile.tib.area2]=Disk /var;default_queue;area-unix
fileattribute[hostname.stoop.trb.area]=Disk /tmp;default_queue;area-unix
```

Here are the Contents of changesfile which contain the wildcard and escaped characters to correctly pass the info to sed are below:

```
.*hostname\.stoop\.trb\.area.*Disk.*\/tmp.*area\-unix$
.*hostname\.stile\.tib\.area2.*Disk.*\/var.*area\-unix$
```

So far nothing is working. Some commands remove the regex plus other stuff. Not sure why. Any advice is much appreciated. No one at my workplace has been helpful yet.

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind. Can you please explain further? (I try to be helpful)

Comment: Stackoverflow is ignoring your attempt to use `<br>` and `</br>` for formatting. For code, separate with a blank line from text above, and use 4 spaces at the begining of each line. Good luck.

Comment: `cat changesfile | while read i ; do sed -ie "s/$i//g" filename ; done` will delete the lines from changefile that are found in filename.

Comment: learn to read man pages? `man sed` now search for the diffence between the `-e` and `-i` arguments. Then get a small test case to work, without the while loop, just `sed  's/crazypattern//' small_oneLine_file`, until you get the output you want. Then do a 2 line file where the 2nd line shouldn't be deleted. Is that working, now put your $s value into a file, and use your while loop with only the 2 small tests. When that is working, you'll have to look at the rest of your search targets and make them work, either via the same process, or with a big gamble will all files and targets! Good luck.

Comment: do `set -x` in the bash script (or in the running shell if you are testing there—cancel it with `set +x`). This causes bash to print the command just before it runs it, and gives you a chance to see the results of the various expansions going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -i -r -f changesfile filename
```

**Explanation**

1. `-r` - Use extended regular expressions in the script. No need to escape special characters.
2. `-f` - Add the contents of script-file to the commands to be executed.

Comment: so your saying put :

    fileattribute[hostname.stile.tib.area2]=Disk /var;default_queue;area-unix

    fileattribute[hostname.stoop.trb.area]=Disk /tmp;default_queue;area-unix

into changesfile? The exact lines, and that will just remove them from the filename?

Comment: Add the full sed commands to the `changesfile`, one per line.